# Utilizar un mismo ArrayList en distintos métodos

Tags: java

Tengo un problema, intento trabajar con un `ArrayList` en el que introducir distintas clases, pero si creo el arreglo dentro de `main`, no me lo reconoce en los métodos que quiero emplear.

¿Se supone que debo llamarlo desde cada método que vaya a realizar alguna función (add, delete, size...)?

Este es el código de `main` (por supuesto me da error al llamar a `maquina1` en cada método):

```
package EjercicioMaquinas;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class MainMaquina extends Maquina {
    public static void main (String [] args){
        ArrayList maquina1 = new ArrayList ();
        menu();
    }


    public static void menu(){
        System.out.println("elige opción: 1-añadir máquina  2-medir lista  3-eliminar máquina  4-salir");

        Scanner myScan = new Scanner(System.in);
        int option = myScan.nextInt();
        switch (option){
            case 1: addMachine();break; //Añadir elemento
            case 2: askSize();break;    //ver tamaño 
            case 3: deleteMachine() ;break; //Eliminar elemento
            case 4: System.out.println("adios");break;  //Salir
            default: menu();break;
            }
        }
    public static void addMachine(){    
        System.out.println("¿qué quieres añadir?: 1) lavadora \n 2)frigorifico \n 3)televisor \n 4)nada");
        Scanner myScan = new Scanner (System.in);
        int option = myScan.nextInt();
        switch (option){
            case 1: maquina1.add(new Lavadora());menu();break;
            case 2: maquina1.add(new Frigorifico());menu();break;
            case 3: maquina1.add(new Televisor());menu();break;
            case 4: System.out.println("de acuerdo, adios");
            default: System.out.println("opción incorrecta, pruebe otra vez");addMachine();break;
        }
    }
    public static void askSize(){
        maquina1.size();
    }
    public static void deleteMachine(){
        maquina1.remove(maquina1);menu();break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Al declarar el ArrayList en una clase fuera de main e inicializándola después desde la clase main desaparece el error, pero al ejecutar me salta un error de java.lang.NullPointerException, no entiendo bien de que se trata.

Comment: Estas declarando `maquina1` dentro del `main()`, creala fuera de este de la siguiente forma: `private static ArrayList maquina1;` y dentro del `main` pon: `maquina1 = new ArrayList();`. Eso debería resolver tu problema.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Una vaga solución:

```
public class MainMaquina extends Maquina {
    private static ArrayList maquina1 = new ArrayList ();
    public static void main (String [] args){
        maquina1 = new ArrayList(); // Creas la nueva instancia en el Main()
        menu();
    }
```

Ahora sí se debería poder agregar/eliminar y otras tareas desde otros métodos.

---

Pero, una solución mejor implementada sería, crear tu propia clase que trabaje los elementos:

```
// Maquina.java
public class Maquina 
{
    // Implementacion de Maquina, como tipo, etc...
}

// AdmMaquinas.java
public class AdmMaquinas
{
    private ArrayList Maquinas;
    private void Agregar() { /* ... */ }
    private void TamanioLista() { /* ... */ }
    private void Eliminar() { /* ... */ }
    public void IniciarMenu()
    {
        // Implementación...
    }
    public AdmMaquinas() { Maquinas = new ArrayList(); }
}
```

Y en el `static void main()`:

```
AdmMaquinas Programa = new AdmMaquinas();
Programa.IniciarMenu(); // Iniciaria tu programa escrito en la clase anterior.
```

Comment: Si quisiera crear máquinas diferentes (maquina frigorífico, maquina televisor...) ¿Debería crear clases independientes para cada una de ellas con esta misma estructura (AdmMaquinas) ?

Comment: @Isilion pues depende de tus necesidades, ejemplo, si una lavadora tiene un modelo, tienes una clase de tipo `Maquina` que tiene sus respectivos atributos que la identifican,  pero imagina que una lavadora tiene funciones que un televisor no puede hacer, no puedes obligar al televisor a lavar... Por eso extiendes una clase, pero si solo almacenaras eso, no es necesaria la clase general.

Answer (score 1):

¿Tiene alguna intencion declararlo dentro del Main? En caso contrario lo puedes declarar como atributo privado dentro de la clase, y en caso de necesitar un Main puedes utilizar una clase especifica para ejectuar el Main y en este instanciar la clase, existen patrones (Ej: singleton) para que las clases no sean instanciadas más de una vez, si solo quieres tener un objeto Maquina. Si necesitas trabajar con diferentes clases dentro del ArrayList puedes utilizar herencia y declarar que el contenido va a ser del tipo padre, o declarar el contenido como Object que es el padre de todos en java. Si vas a trabajar con instancias de diferentes clases dentro del ArrayList recuerda utilizar instance of para comprobar de que tipo de instancia se trata en cada caso y asi evitar posibles errores. Espero que te sirva de ayuda, no sé si es exactamente lo que necesitabas. Saludos.

**EDIT:**

Si lo que necesitas es almacenar diferentes clases en un mismo ArrayList lo mejor es la segunda opcion:

Declarar el ArrayList como **un ArrayList de Objetos**:

```
ArrayList<Object> lista = new ArrayList<Object>();
```

De esta forma **podrás introducir cualquier clase** en el ArrayList, a la hora de recorrerlo, deberas comprobar que tipo de objeto se trata en cada caso para poder evitar excepciones (classCastException, noSuchMetodException entre otras), lo puedes hacer de la siguiente forma: (Ejemplo con un arraylist que contenga tanto Integer como String)

```
for (Object obj : lista ) {
  if(obj instanceof String)
  {
    //your code
  }
  if(obj instanceof Integer)
  {
    //your code
  }
}
```

Y asi podrás tratar cada objeto de acuerdo con sus métodos y atributos especificos. De está forma podrás utilizar las utilidades propias de la lista sobre cualquier clase y después realizar las acciones necesarias sobre cada objeto.

**LA OTRA OPCIÓN**

En caso de que tengas atributos/métodos comunes a las clases en las que vas a tener puedes utilizar la herencia:

```
public class Animal {
      private String nombre;
}

public class Mamifero extends Animal{
     private int numPatas;
}

public class Pez extends Animal{
     private int numAletas;
}
```

Mediante la Clausula

> extends

Estaremos indicando que Mamifero y Pez son clases hijas de Animal (he aqui el concepto de herencia) de esta forma ambas tendrán ademas de sus métodos y atributos, aquellos contenidos de la clase padre.

Teniendo esto podemos declarar el ArrayList de la siguiente forma:

```
 ArrayList<Animal> animales = new ArrayList<Animal>();
```

De esta forma podrá contener objetos de clase Animal , y aquellos de sus clases hijas, en este caso Pez y Mamifero. La forma de acceder posteriormente será similar al caso anterior.

*Como Aclaración*

En realidad en ambos casos estamos haciendo lo mismo, porque todas las clases tienen un `extends Object` implicito, el cual no debe anotarse. En el segundo solo estamos siendo un poco más específicos.

Comment: Es mejor si acompañas tus sugerencias con ejemplos, así les sirve a todos.

Comment: Me interesa trabajar con diferentes clases, pero no entiendo la cuestión de declarar una clase como padre, ¿Cómo especifico la clase padre y heredadas para que no confundirme dentro del arrayList?

Comment: Añado el ejemplo en un EDIT, espero que te sirva, si tienes alguna duda pregunta de nuevo. Saludos.